# Steam friends login

Tags: steam

My Steam doesn't login into the friend list since long ago.

Today I tried to fix it and stumbled upon [this](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/SteamClientBeta/discussions/1/810939350937498653/)

> Under Settings - Friends I have "Automatically sign into Friends when I start Steam" unchecked. This has always worked fine. After yesterdays beta update the steam client keeps signing me into friends when I start Steam after it has been fully closed. The option is still off though so it shouldn't be.

Basically an exact explanation of my problem.

A valve member [answered there already](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/SteamClientBeta/discussions/1/810939350937498653/#c648816742505251972)
saying it was already fixed and had something to do with the Family Options. I also have this option enabled but somehow it still doesn't logon.

Anyone else had this problem/fixed it already?

Comment: What happens if you try to log in? Do you have family view enabled? Did you try a refresh of your steam files?

Comment: What do you want now? Automatically login or not? Because the mentioned option will DO the login if checked, whereas the user you quoted DID NOT want it and therefore left it unchecked, but it logs him in. How is this exactly what you have?

Comment: How could I've over read this issue. I want it to automatically log me in. Regoogeling my issue resolved around deleting everything except steam and the game files and re-download everything. So I'll try that. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this seems to be a problem of Steam Client Beta, you gotta wait for Valve to fix it. The obvious solution is to opt-out of the Steam Client Beta the same way you opted in.